# request_mem_region failing because of overlapping memory

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04

I understand that I am running the Tesla K80 not in its preferred environment, but I have seen regular consumers use this product successfully so I tried it myself.https://blog.thomasjungblut.com/random/running-tesla-k80/

I followed [this](https://sjgf.medium.com/a-tesla-k80-and-ubuntu-in-a-consumer-motherboard-ab0edbf0e0d1), with an bit more up to date ubuntu version (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) and the driver from [here](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/182241/en-us/), but the graphics cards memory is unassigned

```
/sbin/lspci -d "10de:*" -v -xxx

03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK210GL [Tesla K80] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 106c
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at <unassigned> (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled]
    Memory at <unassigned> (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] #19
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

I think this is claiming the memory

```
[    0.193803] pnp 00:00: disabling [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed44fff] because it overlaps 0000:03:00.0 BAR 1 [mem 0x00000000-0x3ffffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.193803] pnp 00:00: disabling [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed44fff disabled] because it overlaps 0000:04:00.0 BAR 1 [mem 0x00000000-0x3ffffffff 64bit pref]
```

A other synthome of this problem is that my tty2 get flooded with this these messages:

```
[  606.073710] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 2 device(s).
[  606.073711] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA devices were initialized.
[  606.073942] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 511
[  606.553951] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 511
[  606.553958] NVRM: request_mem_region failed for 0M @ 0x0. This can
               NVRM: occur when a driver such as rivatv is loaded and claims
               NVRM: ownership of the device's registers.
[  606.554683] nvidia: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -1
```

So the only other graphics drivers that were installed and not blacklisted(like the nouveau) where the intel i915, but blacklisting them, got me these errors

```
   16.326014] NVRM: GPU 0000:03:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x22:0xffff:667)
[   16.326053] NVRM: GPU 0000:03:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
[   16.444268] NVRM: GPU 0000:04:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x22:0xffff:667)
[   16.444304] NVRM: GPU 0000:04:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 1
[   16.562258] NVRM: GPU 0000:04:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x22:0xffff:667)
```

Since the Nvidia Tesla K80 does not have video output, I prefer having the integrated graphics card drivers installed.

```
~> mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode
```

Here a bit more information about my system [nvidia-bugreport.sh](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/uploads/short-url/8O66DH5T13VVrVa5wLqJInoFcOi.gz)